# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 14.04 macmini

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I just installed 14.04 on a Mac Mini, and the wireless drivers are not working.  I went into "additional drivers" and choose the broadcom proprietary drivers (like I did in 12.04) but they're not working correctly.  The drivers work fine in 12.04 but not in 14.04 so I'm not sure what the problem is.

`lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` shows:

```
03:300.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
```

Any ideas? I've activated the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source with no luck.

So I loaded in the b43 driver (using `modprobe b43`) and now I can scan for wireless networks, but I can't connect to any of them.  It sits trying to connect and then errors out.  The other driver (wl) doesn't seem to want to scan for wireless networks at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449542/14-04-wireless-connection-error-for-some-networks#comment590356_449542

Comment: If it worked in 12.04 but not 14.04 maybe is a bug.

Comment: I found that it is specific to certain routers... I have an older netgear router at home that i can connect flawlessly to using 13.10, but on two separate computers with 14.04LTS it fails to connect. It does connect to my phone's hotspot and the hotspot at work though...

Comment: Trusty Tahr Wifi works fine on my Macmini4,1(Mid-2010). LSHW shows it to be a **BCM43224** using driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941).

Comment: However, I too have seen wifi performance vary based upon the WAP technology in use. On my Lenovo Ideapad U430 running Ubuntu-GNOME 1404, connectivity to my ASUS RT-N66U Dark Knight running custom firmware 3.0.0.4.374.32 (Merlin build) works great. At school, the Aruba infrastructure wifi isn't worth a crap for connectivity in Ubuntu...but works very well in Windows. I wonder if Network-Manager has some new wonky behaviors(bug?) with 14.04?

Comment: This may not solve this precise problem, but I spent hours on a mysterious wifi problem after updating to 14.04. The problem was solved by forcing my router to work at only 802.11g rather than n. I think that the router and Ubuntu both thought they could use 802.11n but the old Broadcom adaptor on my HP Netbook, could only handle g standard.