# Wireless connection error for SOME networks

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I have just installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and everything about wireless was ok until I come to work. 14.04 recognized & successfully connected to my home wireless network but it does not connect to my work wireless network. I'm able to see my work wireless network but always get connection error. Here is the related `syslog`:

```
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'WIFI-AIBU'
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'WIFI-AIBU' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'WIFI-AIBU'
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 18 11:36:57 talha-HP wpa_supplicant[755]: message repeated 5 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Apr 18 11:36:58 talha-HP wpa_supplicant[755]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 3c:94:d5:3e:10:82 (SSID='WIFI-AIBU' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr 18 11:36:58 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP wpa_supplicant[755]: wlan0: Associated with 3c:94:d5:3e:10:82
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP wpa_supplicant[755]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 3c:94:d5:3e:10:82 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.444046] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: TR
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'WIFI-AIBU'.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> dhclient started with pid 3072
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.450186] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: TR
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.450191] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.450194] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.450196] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.450198] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP kernel: [ 1273.450201] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6627:37ff:fe56:afb9 on wlan0.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::6627:37ff:fe56:afb9.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: All rights reserved.
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: 
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/64:27:37:56:af:b9
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/64:27:37:56:af:b9
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 18 11:36:59 talha-HP dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x8c5113b)
Apr 18 11:37:00 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::6627:37ff:fe56:afb9.
Apr 18 11:37:00 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 18 11:37:00 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Registering new address record for fe80::6627:37ff:fe56:afb9 on wlan0.*.
Apr 18 11:37:02 talha-HP dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x8c5113b)
Apr 18 11:37:10 talha-HP dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x8c5113b)
Apr 18 11:37:24 talha-HP dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x8c5113b)
Apr 18 11:37:40 talha-HP dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x8c5113b)
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <warn> (wlan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3072
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Marking connection 'WIFI-AIBU' invalid.
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'WIFI-AIBU'
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6627:37ff:fe56:afb9 on wlan0.
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::6627:37ff:fe56:afb9.
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP avahi-daemon[722]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP wpa_supplicant[755]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=3c:94:d5:3e:10:82 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Apr 18 11:37:44 talha-HP wpa_supplicant[755]: nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
```

**p.s. Additional information**

- It successfully connects to my mobile phone's WiFi too.
- I was able to connect **same network** yesterday using **Ubuntu 12.04**.

**Edit: Output of lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1795]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1670]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: **Jockey** is replaced and _Trusty_ uses ubuntu-drivers-common which works in terminal! You need to install some packages. Try `ubuntu-drivers devices` to determine them!

Comment: here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7275194/ @onrea

Comment: So, Install it by `apt-get`. (details: https://www.google.com/search?q=bcmwl-kernel-source)

Comment: @onrea I have already installed latest version of `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Works fine on my linksys wifi network, but refuses my home netgear one. Works on my phone as well. Seems a bit buggy at the moment.

Comment: Any news? I just upgraded to 14.04 and think I have the same problem.

Comment: @dranxo unfortunately nothing new.. reported in lauchpad: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/248541